# How can I convert Base64 image to file type

Tags: javascript, html, base64, filereader

I want to inject my site to ios device and I need to use the device's camera.

It returns a base64 image type. When the camera is finished, can I convert that to a file type?

If mobile device return a file path, can I reset it to a input element (with type="file") and then reuse fileReader to read it? How to do it?

If mobile device return a file path, can I set the `<img>` element's src attribute? will it show?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry, there is no demo, because I will use the device. I use the ios device's camera to take photos, is return me a base64 data the a uri( image path in mobile device ),

Answer (score 0):

you can get it from client in base64 format and the convert it to image file in server side using php:

```
function base64_convert_to_jpeg($base64_string_in, $file_out) {
   $fp = fopen($file_out, "wb"); // this open file writable and binary 

   $data = explode(',', $base64_string_in);  //explode base64 string with ',' character

   fwrite($fp, base64_decode($data[1])); //decode base64 and write it to file
   fclose($fp);  //close the file 

   return $file_out; //return jpeg file
```

}

if you have problem with it or you have any question about that, replay that for me...
good luck